# Complicated string replace

Tags: vba, excel

I have some data that gets pulled on a weekly basis and looks terrible, so I have a formatting sheet that puts the data in a more friendly format that's readable.

Unfortunately management decided to add a column in the raw data, which throws off all of my cell references by 1 column. Here's my current code in the cells:

```
=IF(([SPREADSHEETREF.xlsx]Raw1!AD3)=0,"-",([SPREADSHEETREF.xlsx]Raw1!AD3))
```

I need to "add" one column to the current references.  So that in the above example, it would replaces `AD3` with `AE3`.

I was thinking of using `WorksheetFunction.Replace( old_text, start, number_of_chars, new_text )`, but I'm not sure it would work in this case.

I can't seem to figure out how to make the `new_text` some type of value addition, so that it's like `OldValue + 1 = AE`.  The columns being referenced are all over the place, so I need the flexibility of using like a +1 formula to do this.

Comment: With your source and "formatting" workbooks open ,insert a column in your source sheet.  Your formatting formulas should adjust accordingly.

Comment: Holy crap.  I cannot believe it was that simple.  CURSE YOU EXCEL.

Answer (score 0):

The following function will shift AD1 to AE1:

```
Function ShiftAddress(CellAddress As String, Optional shift As Long = 1) As String
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Range(CellAddress)
    ShiftAddress = R.Offset(0, shift).Address(False, False)
End Function
```

ShiftAddress("AD1") returns "AE1". ShiftAddress("AD1",2) returns "AF1", etc.